# (ag-Grid)How to display header at the top if some column group has no children

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

In [this demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/#example-marry-children) from ag-Grid.

`Age` field is display at the bottom.

[image: demo]

How to display `Age` field at the top?

Thanks!

.

`ColumnDefs` looks like :

```js
return [
    {
      headerName: 'Athlete Details',
      headerClass: 'participant-group',
      children: [
        {
          field: 'athlete',
          colId: 'athlete',
        },
        ...
      ],
    },
    {
      // how to display this field's harder at top
      field: 'age',
      colId: 'age',
    },
    ...
  ];
```

Comment: Make a new object in the array with headerName: 'Age' and put in the children array your field 'age' and colId 'age'

Comment: It works with set children's headerName to empty in order to hide the name.
But it's a little bit tricky.